# Get first date that account-prod get discount sql

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I have a huge volume of  a history of transactions table with acc_nbr, tran_nbr, tran_amt, tran_dt, and tran_dis tran_prd

I need to find the first date for each acc_nbr and tran_prd

Find the First date When the account with this type of product purchase it with a discount

Lets say we have the below input table for the same account number :

| tran_dt | acc_nbr | tran_prd | tran_amt | tran_dis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-1-2020 | 666 | A | 777 | 0 |
| 3-4-2020 | 666 | A | 777 | 0 |
| 5-5-2021 | 666 | C | 222 | 18 |
| 7-1-2022 | 666 | A | 777 | 20 |
| 3-5-2023 | 666 | A | 777 | 99 |

And i want the output be  :

| acc_nbr | tran_prd | Effective dis date | tran_amt (sum) | tran_dis sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 666 | A | 7-1-2022 | 1,554 | 119 |
| 666 | C | 5-5-2021 | 222 | 18 |

Comment: What have you tried, what doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I presume you’re summing some of the other values but you haven’t explained that - what are you summing and what are the rules for which rows to include?

Comment: You can use a subquery to find the Effective_dis_date, i.e. MIN(tran_dt) for each acc_nbr, tran_prd where tran_dis is nonzero.  Then join that back to the original table and SUM.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #tran_hist
(
    tran_dt date,
    acc_nbr int,
    tran_prd varchar(1),
    tran_amt int,
    tran_dis int
)

insert into #tran_hist values
('2020-1-1',666,'A',777,0),
('2020-4-3',666,'A',777,0),
('2021-5-5',666,'C',222,18),
('2022-1-7',666,'A',777,20),
('2023-5-3',666,'A',777,99)

select
    acc_nbr,
    tran_prd,
    min(tran_dt) as [Effective dis date],
    sum(tran_amt) as [tran_amt (sum)],
    sum(tran_dis) as [tran_dis sum]
from #tran_hist
where tran_dis <> 0
group by acc_nbr,
         tran_prd

drop table #tran_hist
```

Results:

```
/-------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| acc_nbr | tran_prd | Effective dis date | tran_amt (sum) | tran_dis sum |
|---------|----------|--------------------|----------------|--------------|
|   666   |    A     |     2022-01-07     |      1554      |     119      |
|   666   |    C     |     2021-05-05     |       222      |      18      |
\-------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```